# Power Automate: I want to move Date&Time column of Excel file (OneDrive) to SharePoint List using Power Automate

Tags: excel-formula, sharepoint-online, onedrive, power-automate

I am able to move all my columns of excel file which is present in OneDrive to SharePoint list using Power Automate except date & time column of excel file.

Power Automate converts date & time field into a decimal number. What formula do I have to use to convert that number again to date & time?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution in another forum. Below formula we have to use.

addseconds('1899-12-30', int(formatNumber(mul(float(item()?['Date']),86400),'0','en-in')),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

in this 'Date' is the excel column name and 'en-in' you can change according to your time zone.